# Implicit cast caused StackOverflowException in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception, stack-overflow

I have a custom Class called BoolReference.
I am using implicit cast to assign bool values to this class without calling it's Value property.
Here is the code where second cast method causes stack overflow and can someone help me to fix this?

```
[System.Serializable]
public class BoolReference {
[SerializeField]
private BoolVariable Variable;

public bool Value {
    get => Variable.Value;
    set {
        Variable.Value = value;
    }
}

public static implicit operator bool(BoolReference bRef) => bRef.Value;
public static implicit operator BoolReference(bool b) => b;

}
```

This is usage which causes the exception

```
public BoolReference IsInPlay;

void Awake() {
    IsInPlay = false;    
}
```

If i write IsInPlay.Value = false, then everything is ok

Comment: And what, pray tell, is a `BoolVariable`?

Comment: It's like pattern to cleverly use scriptableobjects in unity, and BoolVariable is custom scriptableojbect

Comment: When you use `IsInPlay = false;`, it will cast `false` using `public static implicit operator BoolReference(bool b) => b` which returns a bool, which is still not a VariableBool, and will be cast in bool the same way, return a bool which is not a VariableBool... and so on. The thing is you have to do something like `public static implicit operator BoolReference(bool b) => new VariableBool(b);`

Comment: @Malphegal agreed, except OP can't use that either since `BoolVariable != BoolReference` ;) @OP what is the purpose of this in-between class? Why not just directly use the `BoolVariable` objects? You probably can not have an implicit operator back to `BoolReference` unless you know exactly what shall happen there / if/how a new ScriptableObject shall be created and assigned..

Comment: This question definitely seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359), but I answered it anyway. I have a feeling it won't be the answer asker is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually returning a `BoolReference` in the conversion operator worked for me:

```
using System;

public class BoolVariable {
    public bool Value;
}

public class BoolReference {

private BoolVariable Variable;

public bool Value {
    get => Variable.Value;
    set {
        Variable.Value = value;
    }
}

public static implicit operator bool(BoolReference bRef) => bRef.Value;
public static implicit operator BoolReference(bool b){
    BoolReference br = new BoolReference();
    br.Variable = new BoolVariable();
    br.Value=b;
    return br;
}

}   
public class Program
{
    static BoolReference r;
    public static void Main()
    {
        r = false;
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        r = true;
        Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
```

...[which prints](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OXKFiW):

> ```
> false
> true
> ```